# B-Movie. Spaceship uses chickens as a power-source. Planets shaped like butts

Tags: story-identification, movie

So there's this movie my friend keeps remembering watching some years back on the TV, which sounds SO BAD that I really want to find it and have a look as well!

Unforgettable details you'd remember if you've watch it:

- There is some spaceship, using CHICKENS as power source. They just throw them inside an oven, or generator or similar.
- There where PLANETS SHAPED LIKE "BUTTS", that where.. FARTING and the spaceship crew had to somehow put CORKS in them to stop it and survive the blasts....
- I think the main plot was alien women searching for a male from their planet, [which they saw on a magazine (?)] and arrived on Earth.
- the movie was colored not B&W.

I might learn some more if I see my friend again, but the above items, must really be unforgettably bad to my imagination.

Comment: I don't know about the chickens or anything else, but the second point sounds like Flesh Gordon, which had an "assteroid belt" complete with corks which you can look up on youtube...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not want to see this movie: **Flesh Gordon Meets the Cosmic Chearleaders**

From imdb (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097365/parentalguide)

> The spaceship is shaped like a penis. The spaceship is powered by chickens having sex.

And [it has farting, butt-shaped asteroids](https://mondobizarrocinema.blogspot.com/2009/06/pornedy-flesh-gordon-ii.html):

[image]

The description of the plot matches more of your details.

> Space-faring hero and galactically-renowned stud Flesh Gordon is kidnapped by a group of space cheerleaders hoping to use him to save their planet. A being simply known as Evil Presence has been rendering the men of their world impotent, and the women are desperate for some form of relief. Flesh's girlfriend Ardor, meanwhile, is following behind to try to keep him out of trouble, but soon finds herself kidnapped by Evil Presence's henchman who has plans of his own. Can Flesh get the men of this planet standing tall once again?

I'm going to spoil the movie for you by revealing that the answer to that question is

> Yes!

Comment: And the planets? Were they shaped like giant farting butts?

Comment: valorum I think so, but I may be conflating that with the original Flesh Gordon movie which, as @moopet noted above, had them.  However, I don't think the original had the chicken powered spaceships.

Comment: [According to this review](https://mondobizarrocinema.blogspot.com/2009/06/pornedy-flesh-gordon-ii.html), yes, it had farting butt planets.

Comment: Curiosity has shown me some strange things...

Comment: I'm going to second "You do not want to see this movie"

Comment: Guys you are amazing!

This movie isn't though :P

Doesn't matter, we'll have fun making fun of it.
Thanks a lot!